# Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className` ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

> I have component with the following code:
> And it gives an error: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

```
export default function TodoItem({ todo }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return (
    <li className={todo.completed && "complete"}>
        <div className="view">
          <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" />
          <label onDoubleClick={ () => dispatch(updateTodo(todo.title))}>{todo.title}</label>
          <button className="destroy" onClick={ () => dispatch(deleteTodo(todo.id))} />
        </div>
        <input className="edit" defaultValue="Create a TodoMVC template" />
    </li>
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: `className={todo.completed && "complete"}` -----> `className={todo.completed ? "complete" : ""}`

Answer (score 0):

Man your expression todo.completed && "complete" will return a boolean value (false in this case) you should do something like this todo.complete ? "completed" : ""

```
className = {todo.completed ? "completed" : ""}
```

Comment: No problem sir, If this answer is correct mark as correct please, so other people can jump right in.

Comment: before that i tried your way but i entered wrong classname

Comment: It happens ahuahuah

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The **&&** expression returns a boolean in classname, you can instead use **ternary operator**, check the fixed code below

```
 export default function TodoItem({ todo }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
   return (
     <li className={todo.completed ? "complete" : ''}>
      {/*FIX using Ternary Operator*/}
      <div className="view">
      <input className="toggle" type="checkbox" />
      <label onDoubleClick={ () => dispatch(updateTodo(todo.title))}> 
       {todo.title}</label>
          <button className="destroy" onClick={ () => 
            dispatch(deleteTodo(todo.id))} />
        </div>
       <input className="edit" defaultValue="Create a TodoMVC template" />
    </li>
  )
 }
```